# Bootstrap Active list / Text aligning

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started playing around with bootstrap earlier today and I have run into some issues trying to have an active tab, as well as alignment of the text.

What I am trying to do is have the tab highlighted when it is on the current section, for some reason only the first tab, Overview, stays highlighted even though it switches to another tab.

Next I was wondering how I would adjust it so the text starts right next to the tabs instead of at the end or after all the tabs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div><div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="tabBars" style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <div class = "list-group">
    <a data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item active" href="#overview">Overview</a>
    <a data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item" href="#classes">Classes</a>
    <a data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item" href="#features">Features</a>
    <a data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item" href="#ranks">Ranks</a>
    <a data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item" href="#faq">F.A.Q</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="tab-content mainArea">
        <div id="overview" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Overview</h3>
            <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="classes" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Classes</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="features" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Features</h3>
            <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis. Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ranks" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Ranks</h3>
            <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

This currently outputs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLF0J.png (can't post images)

As you can see I have the classes tab open, but it still is leaving the overview tab highlighted. The text is also starting below where I am trying to get it to start next to the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this jQuery script to set the selected tab to `active`

**script:**

```
 $('.tabBars > div > a').click( function() {
    $('.tabBars > div > .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
} );
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfdygvhw/)**